# Example mq_timedreceive

Tags: c, linux, timeout, message-queue

I can not find how to work properly with mq_timedreceive, can anyone give me an example?

```
ssize_t mq_timedreceive(mqd_t mqdes, char *msg_ptr,
                   size_t msg_len, unsigned *msg_prio,
                   const struct timespec *abs_timeout);
```

I want timereceive to do not spent more than 20 seconds waiting.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct   timespec tm;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm);
tm.tv_sec += 20;  // Set for 20 seconds
if( 0 > mq_timedreceive( fd, buf, 4096, NULL, &tm ) )  {
  ...
}
```

Take a look at the full description [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/m/mq_timedreceive.html)