# Why does mq_timedreceive ignore the timespec struct?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am trying to get an mq_timedreceive to work, that waits for one second for a message to arrive, prints a char on fail and the message on success. Unfortunately it ignores the timepec struct and just prints the chars immediately. First I've tried to declare a const struct like so:

```
const struct timespec time = {1, 0}; // being {seconds, nanoseconds}
```

I then thought maybe it ignores the seconds and goes for the nanoseconds, so I found this example

[Example mq_timedreceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655148/example-mq-timedreceive)

Unfortunately it also doesn't work and mq_timereceive returns: Resource tempoarily unavailable. But well, that is exactly what I want, but after one second...

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                        } while (0)

char msg_ptr[MAX_SIZE]; // Buffer for mq_receive
char msq_name[] = "/mymsq";
unsigned int msg_prio = 1;
size_t msg_size;
mqd_t mqd; // POSIX message queue descriptor

int main() {


    struct mq_attr attr;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_SIZE;

    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    time.tv_sec += 1000;


    mqd = mq_open(msq_name, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0664, &attr);

    if(mqd == (mqd_t) -1)
        errExit("mq_open");
    else
        printf("Message queue with mqd: %d opened!\n", mqd );

    if(mq_getattr(mqd, &attr) == -1)
        errExit("mq_getattr");

    while(1) {
        msg_size = mq_timedreceive(mqd, msg_ptr, sizeof(msg_ptr), &msg_prio, &time);
        if(msg_size != -1) {
            printf("Received message: %s\n", msg_ptr);
            printf("Message size: %d\n", (int) msg_size);
        }
        if(msg_size == -1) 
            errExit("mq_timedreceive");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The man page does say that the message buffer must be _greater_ than `attr.mq_msgsize`, not greater than or equal to. What is the value of `errno` after this returns -1?

Comment: Also, you're opening in non-blocking mode, so of course it returns immediately if no message is available. That's why you get the "Resource temporarily unavailable" message, and `errno` is probably `EAGAIN`.

Comment: The buffer size and mq_msgsize are both equal to MAX_SIZE. It also says that the O_NONBLOCK is a requirement for the function to block within the specified timeout. Otherwise it would always block... Haven't checked the errno yet, but I guess it points to "Resource temporarily unavailable", since am using a wrapper for perror().